# tensorflow CTC runtime error

Tags: tensorflow, nlp, runtime-error

I met a runtime error during training when I tried to applied tensorflow built-in CTC loss function (https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/nn/conectionist_temporal_classification__ctc_) to SynthText dataset. http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/data/scenetext/
It said " Not enough time for target transition sequence (required: 4, available: 0)".
Here is some info for the environment: tensorflow version '0.12.0-rc0'.

I am able to apply tensorflow built-in CTC to Synth90K Dataset with great performance.

It seems like the SynthText dataset is not compilable with tensorflow built-in CTC but Synth90K Dataset could.

Please find the error message as reference

```
step 980, loss = 50.17 (92.1 examples/sec; 0.695 sec/batch)
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:975] Invalid argument: Not enough time for target transition sequence (required: 4, available: 0), skipping data instance in batch: 28
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "multi-gpu-train.py", line 305, in 
tf.app.run()
File "/home/ubuntu/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 43, in run
sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
File "multi-gpu-train.py", line 301, in main
train()
File "multi-gpu-train.py", line 270, in train
_, loss_value = sess.run([train_op, loss])
File "/home/ubuntu/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 766, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
File "/home/ubuntu/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 964, in _run
feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
File "/home/ubuntu/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1014, in _do_run
target_list, options, run_metadata)
File "/home/ubuntu/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1034, in _do_call
raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Not enough time for target transition sequence (required: 4, available: 0), skipping data instance in batch: 28
[[Node: tower_0/CTCLoss = CTCLoss[ctc_merge_repeated=true, preprocess_collapse_repeated=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](tower_0/transpose_2/_555, tower_0/Where, tower_0/sub_2/_557, tower_0/Sum_1/_559)]]

Caused by op u'tower_0/CTCLoss', defined at:
File "multi-gpu-train.py", line 305, in 
tf.app.run()
File "/home/ubuntu/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 43, in run
sys.exit(main(sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
File "multi-gpu-train.py", line 301, in main
train()
File "multi-gpu-train.py", line 179, in train
loss,logits_op,images,labels = tower_loss(scope)
File "multi-gpu-train.py", line 79, in tower_loss
_ = network2.loss(logits,images, labels)
File "/home/ubuntu/experiments/network2_dev/network2.py", line 61, in loss
out = tf.nn.ctc_loss(logit, to_sparse(y), seq_len, time_major=False)
File "/home/ubuntu/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/ctc_ops.py", line 145, in ctc_loss
ctc_merge_repeated=ctc_merge_repeated)
File "/home/ubuntu/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_ctc_ops.py", line 164, in _ctc_loss
name=name)
File "/home/ubuntu/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 759, in apply_op
op_def=op_def)
File "/home/ubuntu/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2240, in create_op
original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
File "/home/ubuntu/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1128, in init
self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Not enough time for target transition sequence (required: 4, available: 0), skipping data instance in batch: 28
[[Node: tower_0/CTCLoss = CTCLoss[ctc_merge_repeated=true, preprocess_collapse_repeated=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](tower_0/transpose_2/_555, tower_0/Where, tower_0/sub_2/_557, tower_0/Sum_1/_559)]]
```

Comment: the target (ground truth) sequence must not be longer than the CTC input sequence.
Could you tell us the ground truth text and the input sequence length of the sample which causes the problems?